# Signature pad is not working in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, image, dart, syncfusion, signaturepad

I am using the `syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad: ^21.1.35` to get the signature from the user.It was working fine in the flutter mobile application but not in the flutter web.

Seems the `toImage()` is not supported in the web or am I doing something wrong.

**Saving Image Code:**

```
final GlobalKey<SfSignaturePadState> signaturePadKey = GlobalKey<SfSignaturePadState();
ui.Image data = await signaturePadKey.currentState!.toImage(pixelRatio: 3.0);
ByteData? bytes = await data.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
String imageEncoded = base64.encode(bytes!.buffer.asUint8List());
```

`Error: Assertion failed: org-dartlang-sdk:///flutter_web_sdk/lib/_engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart:94:16 dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 266:49      throw_ dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 29:3        assertFailed lib/_engine/engine/html/scene_builder.dart 95:34                                  pushTransform packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1414:12                                 toImage dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                _async packages/flutter/src/rendering/layer.dart 1404:27                                 toImage packages/syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad/signaturepad.dart 974:13                 toImage dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                _async packages/syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad/signaturepad.dart 972:27                 toImage packages/syncfusion_flutter_signaturepad/signaturepad.dart 372:31                 toImage packages/tolk2go_tasker/SignaturePage/signature_view_model.dart 33:33             validatingSignature dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                runBody dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                _async packages/tolk2go_tasker/SignaturePage/signature_view_model.dart 28:35             validatingSignature packages/tolk2go_tasker/SignaturePage/signature.dart 156:54                       <fn> packages/flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart 1072:21                               handleTap packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 253:24                              invokeCallback packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 627:11                                     handleTapUp packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 306:5                                      [_checkUp] packages/flutter/src/gestures/tap.dart 239:7                                      handlePrimaryPointer packages/flutter/src/gestures/recognizer.dart 615:9                               handleEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 98:12                           [_dispatch] packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 143:9                           <fn> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/linked_hash_map.dart 21:13          forEach packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 141:17                          [_dispatchEventToRoutes] packages/flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart 127:7                           route packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 460:19                                 handleEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 440:14                                 dispatchEvent packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 337:11                                dispatchEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 395:7                                  [_handlePointerEventImmediately] packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 357:5                                  handlePointerEvent packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 314:7                                  [_flushPointerEventQueue] packages/flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart 295:7                                  [_handlePointerDataPacket] lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1183:13                               invoke1 lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 244:5                                 invokeOnPointerDataPacket lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 147:39                                    [_onPointerData] lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 653:20                                    <fn> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 594:14                                    <fn> lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 288:16                                    loggedHandler lib/_engine/engine/pointer_binding.dart 179:80                                    <fn> dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall`

[image: Error Image]

**Flutter Doctor:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.8, on macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64, locale en-IN)
    • Flutter version 3.7.8 on channel stable at /Volumes/Backup/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 90c64ed42b (2 days ago), 2023-03-21 11:27:08 -0500
    • Engine revision 9aa7816315
    • Dart version 2.19.5
    • DevTools version 2.20.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/casperonflutter/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.2)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 14C18
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.15+0-b2043.56-8887301)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.76.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone (2) (mobile) • 00008030-001548E10C32802E • ios            • iOS 15.3.1 19D52
    • macOS (desktop)     • macos                     • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.6.3 21G419 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)        • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.110

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 0):

I have recently add `window.flutterWebRenderer = "html";` to my index file. Because of that `SfSignaturePad` started to throw error when we use `toImage()` function.

Answer (score 0):

The toImage built-in method in the signature pad is not suitable for converting signatures to images in a web application. Instead, you need to use the renderToContext2D method, which is defined in the state object of the signature pad. To call this method, you'll need to use a global key assigned to the signature pad instance. We have provided links to the relevant user guide documentation and online samples below for your reference.

UG, https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/signaturepad/getting-started#save-signatures-as-images-in-web-mobile-browser

Sample, https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/signature-pad/getting-started